# Which STL object or memory management to be used for dynamic entities

Tags: c++

I am developing applications for large scale computing and have some specific questions regarding the choice of STL objects and/or better memory management techniques to minimize compute resources.

Specifically, my question is the following: I am currently using a STL vector obj to store data from a file which looks like this:

```
x x x x 0 0 0; x x x 0 0 0 0; x x x x x x x;.........
```

I want to make this into:

```
x x x x; x x x; x x x x x x x;............
```

Is there a memory effective and fast way to do this (want to use least amount of memory possible)? Can I make inplace changes? The size of data (including zeros) between each colon in the file is constant.

Comment: I read the vector as is from the file. The question is how do I process the vector in a fast and memory effective way into the format I require?

Comment: Is `x x x x 0 0 0;` store as one element or whole string as one element?

Comment: I store it as say integer vector. I put semicolons for illustration only.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What are all those `x`s and `0`s? What is the type of the elements in this `vector` you're storing that in?

Comment: @SumanVajjala: What do you mean by read as a vector as it is? Does it mean data is read in the vector directly? Or is there a possibility of reading them to self defined doubly/single link list? Sometimes rather than standard STL, self written linklist seems to help in customized activity with faster/better memory managed algo.

Comment: `erase` in `std::vector` would move all elements after the removed one, so it is not quite efficient. If you do not want random access, you could use `std::list`.

Comment: kumar_m_kiran: I read the data from the file into a vector in one-shot. What I want to do is to free the memory held up by zeros, without changing the ordering of the data

Comment: @Praetorian: x's are some values (ints,longs, floats whatever). 0's are ...well zeros. I read the data from a file one-shot. Now, I want to remove zeros, preserving the order. How can I do it efficiently. Hope that makes my question clear!!

Comment: No, it still isn't clear. I don't understand what this *one-shot* reading of a file is, but let's ignore that. So you're reading in a bunch of numbers, but how are you storing them? As strings or converting them to doubles or some other numeric data type?

Answer (score 1):

You could store the numbers and their offsets in separate `std::vector` instances:

```
typedef std::vector<unsigned char> Data;
Data data;
std::vector<Data::size_type> offsets;
```

Comment: I do a one-shot read from the file and store in a vector. The issue is how do I convert this vector into the one I require?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) and afterwards `std::vector::erase`:

```
typedef std::vector<char> data_type;

data_type vec; // fill vector...

const data_type::size_type datasize;
const data_type::size_type zerosize;
const data_type::size_type packagesize = datasize + zerosize;
size_t i = 0;

auto newend = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](data_type::value_type){
    if(i >= datasize && i < packagesize)
        return true; // remove all zeros
    if(i >= packagesize)
        i = 0;
    return false;    // keep all other values
});

vec.erase(newend,vec.end()); // remove old values
vec.shrink_to_fit();
```

Comment: Does the algorithm collect the list of positions in the vector containing zeros and erases them?

Comment: As your information was inconsistent: the current "algorithm" collects all data that has the following format: datasize bytes data, zerosize zero (being removed). If you just want to remove the zeros, use `std::remove(vec.begin(),vec.end(),0)`.